# Deep difference between for loop and comprehension?

Tags: python, boolean, list-comprehension, any

so I'm not a pro at python so I need to know:

Why does this work:

```
s = "test123"
print (any(c.isalnum() for c in s))
```

And this doesn't work (gives "bool" is not iterable error):

```
s = "test123"
for c in s:
    print(any(c.isalnum()))
```

It feels like there is some additional code inside the comprehension that tells it how to deal with iterating over the bools.

Also, it feels like the comprehension stores the bool for each iteration of c over s into a list, from which it calls the any method at the end.
Whereas in the for loop I'd need to create a list of bools and then run the any method on it.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "It feels like there is some additional code inside the comprehension that tells it how to deal with iterating over the bools." No, not at all, because in the first one you **never try to iterate over a bool**, you pass a *generator object* to `any` and generators are iterable and `any` iterates over that generator. In the second example, you pass a bool to `any`. But bool objects aren't iterable

Comment: I think you are right in all the assumptions you make. (Except you are saying `comprehension` when you mean `generator expression`)

Comment: "Also, it feels like the comprehension stores the bool for each iteration of c over s into a list" no, it doesn't do that. It's a generator expression, it creates *a generator*. Not a list. A list comprehension would create a list, `any([c.isalnum() for c in s)])`

Comment: btw the `c.isalnum() for c in s` part inside `any()` is a `generator expression` which `any()` consumes.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. If you are struggling to *understand* the fundamentals of the language, and you can't solve your confusion by following a tutorial, please try Reddit or Quora. Feel free to ask a question here when you have a problem with *writing* code - as long as you've [done your own research first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

The any function expects an iterator as parameter (like the one you used in your first example) and checks the boolean value returned by each iteration.  Your for-loop is doing the iteration and providing values one by one.  So it is up to you to implement the condition checking within the loop and exit as soon as you find a True value.

For example:

```
s = "test123"
result = False
for c in s:
    if c.isalnum():
       result = True
       break
print(result)
```